# INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR return when using Cordova file plugin create file

Tags: android, cordova

Using Cordova file plugin version 1.3.3 to create and write file on Android5.1, Nexus 10,

1. Following the guide https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file, and match what required on this link.
2. Add permission to manifest: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
3. Folder returned by requestFileSystem interface is "file:///storage/emulated/0/", we can access.
4. Tried two options, get the same error:

   preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal"

   preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"

Sample code:

```
var fileInfo = new Object();
fileInfo.createFile = true;
fileInfo.filename = "test.txt";
fileInfo.content = "test";
fileInfo.success = function(){alert("file Info success");};
fileInfo.error = function() {alert("file Info error");};

_write0 = function() {
    if(fileInfo.createFile) {
        var _write1 = function(downloadFolder) {
            theFileSystem.root.getFile(downloadFolder+"/"+fileInfo.filename,{create:true},function(f){
                f.createWriter(function(writer){
                    var _write2 = function() {
                        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                            fileInfo.success();
                        };
                        var raw = atob(fileInfo.content);
                        var rawLength = raw.length;
                        var contentArray = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
                        for(var i=0;i<rawLength;i++) {
                            contentArray[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
                        }
                        var contentBlob = new Blob([contentArray.buffer]);
                        writer.write(contentBlob);
                    };

                    writer.onwriteend = function(evt){_write2();};
                    writer.onerror = function(evt){fileInfo.error();};
                    writer.truncate(0);
                });
            }, function(data){alert("Create File failed."); alert(data);});
        };

        _write1("File/myApp");
    }
};

requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT,1024*1024,function(fs){
    theFileSystem = fs;
    _write0();
},function(data){alert("requestFileSystem failed."); alert(data);});
```

**Error INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR(9) throws when executing into interface DirectoryEntry.prototype.getFile .**

So any other configuration needed for this plugin worked on Android 5.1?

BTW, the code working correctly on iPad.

Comment: did you find any solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Make sure you don't have such special character which creates problem while path creation like '/'

Answer (score 5):

This solution works for me.
Edit the config file to this:

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
   <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/>
  </edit-config>
</plataform>
```

Found solution [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/408#issuecomment-670379873)

Answer (score 0):

These settings worked for me:

```
!npm i -g cordova@10.0.0
!cordova platform add android@9
```

Set target SDK version to 28 in config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

Sampel code for testing:

```
var errorHandler = function (fileName, e) {  
        var msg = '';

        switch (e.code) {
            case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                msg = 'Storage quota exceeded';
                break;
            case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                msg = 'File not found';
                break;
            case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                msg = 'Security error';
                break;
            case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                msg = 'Invalid modification';
                break;
            case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                msg = 'Invalid state';
                break;
            default:
                msg = 'Unknown error';
                break;
        };

    console.log('Error (' + fileName + '): ' + msg);
console.log(e);
}


function testWriting_toDownloads(){
    var text= "Blah Blah Blah";
    var fileName="test-1234-qwerty.txt";
    var blobf = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Download/', function (directoryEntry) {
        console.log('file system open: ' + directoryEntry.name);
        console.log('file system open: ' + directoryEntry.nativeURL);
        directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
            console.log('file system open: ' + fileEntry.name);
            console.log('file system open: ' + fileEntry.nativeURL);
            writeFile(fileEntry, blobf)
        }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
    }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
  

  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the **Storage** is **enabled** in the **App permissions**.
`INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR` is thrown when the App is trying to request a **non-existant** filesystem.